# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, runtime, single-sign-on, owin

I am installing the following packages for a single sign-on in an ASP .NET project:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

They install correctly but when I try to run the project I get the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies
[ERROR TRIGGERED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS4OW.png)

I am using ASP .NET Framework 4.5, does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend to start by double-checking your assembly references in the project and ensure that they are to .NET Framework (most likely net48 but might be another version).

Comment: @leonardo189 did you end up finding the resolution to this question? I am running into the same issue at the moment. It appears as though a file may not be in the dll.